# Google Calendar API > Events: move > Try this API gives 404/403 error

Tags: google-apis-explorer

https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/move

When trying to move a calendar event from one `@gmail.com` account to other it gives 404 error

When trying to move a calendar event from one `@<companyname>.com` account to other it gives 403 error

[image: Image: Event move 403 Error]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you have to add the source calendar to destination calendar before this api can work with "Make changes to events" role selected.

[Image: Add source calendar to destination calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csIY6.jpg)